# Multiple Rooms with Lights

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine, texture-mapping, lighting

I'm in a bit of a predicament and I'm sure I'm not the first one to run into this problem.

I'm trying to model an office building with multiple rooms. I want the player to be able to turn the lights on/off for each room. Here are the problems I'm running into:

Problem 1: With forward rendering I can't use shadows and therefore my point lights leak through the wall (i.e. room with the lights turned off aren't pitch black because they're receiving light from adjacent rooms).

Solution: Initially, I was solving this by light mapping my scene twice - once with lights on and once with lights off. When the player turned the lights off I was switching all renderers in the room to an all black lightmap and turning the light off.

Problem 2: The above solution is not bad, but all of my dynamic objects still receive the light leaking through walls. I think I could fix this using lightprobes. However, I'm not sure how to change the lightmap of individual probes (i.e. the probes in the room use the off lightmap, probes outside the room use the on lightmap).

If I use deferred lighting with shadows everything works good, but my fps drops from 60 to ~20.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Having two light maps is indeed a solution but limits you to static diffuse scenes. Anything else (either moving objects or specular scenes) requires more advanced techniques.

- A simple cheap solution is to use "cell and portals" (e.g., [this paper](http://www-ljk.imag.fr/Publications/Basilic/com.lmc.publi.PUBLI_Techreport@1172c0fd434_91669a/lefebvre-hornus-portals.pdf) ) and keep your first solution. This approach builds a graph representing links between your different rooms and should prevent light from leaking - at least approximately.
- A better solution is to use [shadow maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mapping) . You basically render a depth map of the scene once from the point of view of each light source (if punctual!), and then a simple test allows you to determine whether the current point is in shadows or not. You can of course merge this method with the cell and portals decomposition for faster computations if you have many rooms.
- A possibly even better solution is to use [shadow volumes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_volume). This approach computes the geometric intersection between each light cone (or whatever shape your spot light has) and the geometry of your scene. Using that, you can determine whether the current point is inside or outside of the shadow volume.

All that has been extended to soft shadows if you search on the net.

Comment: Thanks! My current implementation can't use the 'cell and portals' technique as the rooms aren't 'watertight' as explained in the paper (walls can be broken). I also provide a RTS view of the entire building as well so I think the 'cell and portals' method would fail here as well.

Reasearching shadow volumes now..

Comment: note that shadow volumes are much harder to implement than shadow maps. Shadow maps are easily done on the GPU, although shadow volumes need some geometry processing.